# I got an exception while register awareness client

Tags: android

Please help me to register awareness snapshot

In failure Listener I got this message:

> "Snapshot could not be registered:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7503:"

In OnCreate:

```
Awareness.getSnapshotClient(this)
            .getDetectedActivity()
            .addOnSuccessListener(dar -> {
                ActivityRecognitionResult arr = dar.getActivityRecognitionResult();
                Log.i(TAG, "Snapshot was successfully registered.");
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "Snapshot could not be registered: " + e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your manifest file so I'll assume you have set up everything according to the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started)

Check the following two things:

1. Location services are enabled on your device
2. You have turned on the location permission for your specific app

   (Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Permissions -> Location)